# Is there any way to select part of all lines in Pages?

Tags: pages

Is there any way to select part of all lines in pages? For example: I have 100 lines with 100 characters each and I need to select 20 characters from each line.

Can I do it with some kind of shortcut or it is not possible and I have to do it manually?

Comment: Are you limited to the Pages app or could you copy the text to TextEdit, then hold down the option key while dragging vertically 100 lines down and horizontally 20 characters across as described [here](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2014/04/how-to-vertically-select-text-within-textedit.html)?

Comment: Is it Pages for Mac or iOS? and is a line defined as where you break it (Enter) or by when it shifts at the edge of the “virtual paper”?